# Can I use policy based authorization to hide html elements from a user

Tags: authorization, asp.net-authorization, role-based-access-control

I am implementing authorization in my web application for the purposes of hiding some UI or html elements from categories of users.  I know I can use Role based authorization to do that but I am implementing policy based authorization in the application.

I would want to know if Role based authorization is the only way to hide html elements from a user.
If it is not so, can I use policy based authorization and how can I do that.